# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAspectJ'. > build config error: bad sourceroot

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am using aspectj with maven and i am getting this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAspectJ'.
```

> build config error: bad sourceroot: /Users/yosomite/Desktop/Workspace/AndroidWorkspace/HomeDecore/app/src/debug/java

My Gradle is :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven() {
        name 'RoboBinding AspectJPlugin Maven Repository'
        url "https://github.com/RoboBinding/RoboBinding-aspectj-plugin/raw/master/mavenRepo"
        //url "file://D:/git/RoboBinding-aspectj-plugin/mavenRepo"
    }

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.+'
    classpath 'org.robobinding:aspectj-plugin:0.8.4'
}
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'org.robobinding.android-aspectj'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled = false
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    //testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    testApplicationId 'org.robobinding.gallerytest'
    testHandleProfiling true
    testFunctionalTest true

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'UnusedAttribute', 'ValidFragment', 'GradleDependency', 'OnClick', 'MissingPrefix', 'MenuTitle'
    abortOnError false
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven() {
    name 'SonaType snapshot repository'
    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
}
maven() {
    name 'RoboBinding Framework Maven Repository'
    url "file://D:/git/RoboBinding/framework/mavenRepo"
}
maven() {
    name 'RoboBinding CodeGen Maven Repository'
    url "file://D:/git/RoboBinding/codegen/mavenRepo"
}

}

ext {
robobindingVersion = 'latest.integration'
//robobindingVersion = '0.8.8'
}

dependencies {
//compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile ("org.robobinding:robobinding:${robobindingVersion}:with-aop") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0'
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'
compile 'com.github.kikoso:SwipeableCards:1.1-RELEASE@aar'
compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.8@aar'
compile 'com.wunderlist:sliding-layer:1.1.1'
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile files('libs/slider.jar')

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.10@aar'
//aspectPath fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
aspectPath "org.robobinding:robobinding:${robobindingVersion}:with-aop"

apt "org.robobinding:codegen:$robobindingVersion"

androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
}
}
```

The cradle syncs without any error but it throws error while running the app. Anyone with possible solutions?

Comment: I do not use Grade, but rather Maven in connection with AspectJ. But I found two things, maybe they are helpful: Firstly there is a more recent version 0.8.5 of the plugin according to the commits in the GitHub repo. Secondly, someone else seems to have [similar problems](https://github.com/RoboBinding/RoboBinding-aspectj-plugin/issues/1) as you. Maybe it is somehow related to your problem because the error message is the same. See if a plugin upgrade helps you, then I can still convert this comment into an answer.

Comment: i tried to upgrade the version but it dint help

Comment: Well, then upload your project or a minimal version of it reproducing the problem as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to GitHub so as to enable others to help you. This is StackOverflow, it is about code.

Comment: You may try my gradle plugin for aspectJ: https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android
Please, feedback on any issues :)